# ASCII to Json in go

Tags: json, go, ascii, converters

im kinda new to programming but i found that python didnt have the speed i needed so i switched to go, im building a scraper and i need to convert a what looks like to be a ASCII formated string to json but i cant find any good documentation on how to do this in go.

the string i need converted looks something like this: debug%22%3Afalse%2C%22pageOpts%22%3A%7B%22noBidIfUnsold%22%3Atrue%2C%22keywords%22%3A%7B%22no-sno-finn-object_type%22%3A%22private%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-car_make%22%3A%22796%22%2C%22aa-sch-publisher%22%3A%22finn%22%2C%22aa-sch-inventory_type%22%3A%22classified%22%2C%22aa-sch-country_code%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-section%22%3A%22car%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-ad_owner%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22no-sno-publishergroup%22%3A%22schibsted%22%2C%22aa-sch-supply_type%22%3A%22web_desktop%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-subsection%22%3A%22car_used%22%2C%22aa-sch-page_type%22%3A%22object%22%7D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ASCII is a character encoding, not a format. That string looks to be URL-encoded. Once decoded, it does appear to be JSON, but it is not a valid JSON document.

Comment: Thank you guys! like i said, im kinda new to this

Comment: "ASCII formatted string" isn't a thing.

Comment: Where from/how do you get that data? I have a feeling there might be something not qute correct going on before the point at which you're trying to decode this. So, should we have more background, we could possibly come up with better suggestions for you.

Comment: I think the string is intended for dynamic advertising on a car selling site, does this help? @kostix

Comment: No, I rather meant it would be useful to know how do you acquire this string, not what it means ;-) But OK, glad you have it sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by a commenter, your string is URL encoded and can be decoded using [`url.QueryUnescape(...)`](https://godoc.org/net/url#QueryUnescape):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/url"
)

func main() {
  querystr := "debug%22%3Afalse%2C%22pageOpts%22%3A%7B%22noBidIfUnsold%22%3Atrue%2C%22keywords%22%3A%7B%22no-sno-finn-object_type%22%3A%22private%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-car_make%22%3A%22796%22%2C%22aa-sch-publisher%22%3A%22finn%22%2C%22aa-sch-inventory_type%22%3A%22classified%22%2C%22aa-sch-country_code%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-section%22%3A%22car%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-ad_owner%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22no-sno-publishergroup%22%3A%22schibsted%22%2C%22aa-sch-supply_type%22%3A%22web_desktop%22%2C%22no-sno-finn-subsection%22%3A%22car_used%22%2C%22aa-sch-page_type%22%3A%22object%22%7D"

  // Parse the URL encoded string.
  plainstr, err := url.QueryUnescape(querystr)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(plainstr)
  // debug":false,"pageOpts":{"noBidIfUnsold":true,"keywords":{"no-sno-finn-object_type":"private","no-sno-finn-car_make":"796","aa-sch-publisher":"finn","aa-sch-inventory_type":"classified","aa-sch-country_code":"no","no-sno-finn-section":"car","no-sno-finn-ad_owner":"false","no-sno-publishergroup":"schibsted","aa-sch-supply_type":"web_desktop","no-sno-finn-subsection":"car_used","aa-sch-page_type":"object"}

}
```

Your example string appears to be incomplete but eventually it can be decoded into a struct or map using [`json.Unmarshal(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).